# How to open MP4 container video with mp42 codec in Vegas Pro?

Tags: codec, vegas-pro

I've been given an MP4 video with the following information, per MediaInfo

```
General
Complete name                            : E:\306G5562_01.MP4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Commercial name                          : XDCAM EX 35
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (mp42)
File size                                : 3.45 GiB
Duration                                 : 13 min
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 35.6 Mb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-07-16 17:57:03
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-07-16 17:57:03

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Commercial name                          : XDCAM EX 35
Format version                           : Version 2
Format profile                           : Main@High
Format settings, BVOP                    : Yes
Format settings, Matrix                  : Custom
Format settings, GOP                     : M=3, N=12
Codec ID                                 : 61
Duration                                 : 13 min
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 34.0 Mb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 35.0 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.656
Time code of first frame                 : 08:36:53:20
Time code source                         : Group of pictures header
GOP, Open/Closed                         : Open
GOP, Open/Closed of first frame          : Closed
Stream size                              : 3.30 GiB (96%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-07-16 17:57:03
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-07-16 17:57:03
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Format settings, Sign                    : Signed
Codec ID                                 : twos
Duration                                 : 13 min
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 536 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 16 bits
Stream size                              : 153 MiB (4%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-07-16 17:57:03
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-07-16 17:57:03
```

From what I can tell, this is XDCAM EX video, which is encoded in MP42 codec in an MP4 container. Vegas Pro won't even look at it. Says the file cannot be opened. How can I fix this? I can convert it (I've done Handbrake and VLC already to test), but I'd rather not, because I actually have tons of these videos and converting takes lots of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mp42` is the container ID, which Mediainfo wrongly calls a `codec id`. It refers to MPEG-4 Part 14 spec for containers.

XDCAM is actually a Sony variant of MPEG-**2** video. I've worked with XDCAM natively in Vegas, which were in MOV, I believe.

You can use FFmpeg to rewrap these files.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c copy video.mov
```

---

Looks like MOVs only work on Macs. The command below also worked.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c copy video.vob
```

(You'll have to switch to viewing `All Files (*.*)`)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43781/discussion-on-answer-by-mulvya-how-to-open-mp4-container-video-with-mp42-codec-i).

Comment: I upgraded to version 13. Loaded the original MP4 completely and without issue. It was fast too. Thanks again for all your help.